# Isotope: Child elements inside button tag like image or span make button unclickable

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-isotope

I slightly modified Dave DeSandro's [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) example [Combination filters with a function, vanilla JS](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/pOjMdx):

Inside the `<button>` tag I inserted a `<picture>` and a `<span>` tag:

```
<button class="button" data-filter=".red">
  <picture>
    <source data-srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/30/f00/ 1x, https://via.placeholder.com/30/f00/ 2x" type=image/webp>
    <source data-srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/30/f00/ 1x, https://via.placeholder.com/30/f00/ 2x">
    <img class=l src=https://via.placeholder.com/30/f00/ loading=eager alt>
  </picture>
  <span>red</span>
</button>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/dash/pen/NWWBqjW

Now, when directly clicking on the button's child `img` or `span` area (color filter red & blue), nothing happens. I wonder how to make the whole button clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a CSS rule `.button > * {pointer-events: none}` solves the problem.

But there is probably a more elegant way to make the button clickable even when it has child elements. Any ideas?